# Javascript - Regex replace ignoring some special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which can be..

```
Samsung Blu-Ray Player
Samgung Bluray player
Samsung Blu/Ray player
```

and I know want to find and replace bluray (later: to give it a certain color). 
Therefore I want to replace the word using a regex. But no idea about the regex syntax in that case. It should ignore "/" and " " and find the string, case insensitive.

Comment: what are all the possibilities that your `blueray` can suffer ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I am sorry. The special characters should be ignored on all places between B and y. So the regex should search for "b*l*u*r*a*y" where the * can only be special characters.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
var str = "Samsung Blu-Ray Player";
var res = str.replace(/(Blu.*?ray)/gi, '<span style="color:red">$1</span>');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why overcomplicating it? span is unnecessary.

Comment: the OP wanted to color the match, thats why

Comment: yes it will match, my regex is only for coloring the string which means blueray, this is what I understood from the OPs question

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string using

```
str = str.replace(/samsung blu[^\w]?ray player/gi, 'Samsung Blu Ray player')
```

where

- `[^\w]?` - is any nonword character (non alphanumeric)
- The `?` makes it optional
- `/gi` - the flags mean `g`lobal search and case`i`nsensitive

Comment: :))) What about str = "Samsung Blu Ray Player"; ? Faster, cleaner :))

Comment: +1 for your humor :), but `str` might be a larger text, with the phrase appearing multiple times in it.

Answer (score 0):

`/\bblu\s*[^\w]?\s*ray\b/gi`

`\b` the word boundary gives it more conservation from matching `blurayfish` or so

`\s*` makes it white space insensitive so `blu - ray` will match

`[^\w]` matches non-word symbols like `-` , `?` means optional

`gi` means all matches, case insensitive.

here is a more illustrative page, with test cases and explanation alongside.

http://regex101.com/r/gD4xS6

Comment: `/\bblue?\s*[^\w]?\s*ray\b/gi` would be my recommendation for `blue ray`